# Я не понимаю суть *& в С++ UPD. Не могу найти ошибку в коде

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, память

учу C++ по виду на ютубе, и застрял на теме изменения динамический массивов, передаваемых в функцию. Вот видео:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzNksn5wPTg&list=PLQOaTSbfxUtCrKs0nicOg2npJQYSPGO9r&index=80&ab_channel=%23SimpleCode

Я пытался сам понять, что значит *& , но не вдупляю. Буду благодарен за объяснение.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 25;

    cout << "&a " << &a << endl; // &a 0x21eeb8

    int *pA = &a;
    cout << "*a " << pA <<endl; //*a 0x21eeb8
    cout << "*a " << *pA <<endl; // *a 25

    cout << "*&a " << *&a<< endl; //*&a 25
}
```

UPD.
Я должен был написать динамический массив, который копируется в другой массив на 1 элемент больше, но при выводе у меня некоторые элементы не совпадают, ошибка где-то в фунции Increase.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void Fill(int arr[],const int size);
void Show(int arr[],const int size);
void Increase(int arr[],int &size,const int value);

int main()
{
    int value = 999;

    int size = 5;
    int *arr = new int[size]; // выделяем память под массив

    Fill(arr,size); // заполняем массив arr

    Show(arr,size); //  выводим массив arr
        cout << endl<< "arr "<<arr << endl;

    Increase(arr,size,value); // Увеличиваем массив на 1

    cout << endl;

    Show(arr,size); // выводим обновлённый массив 
        cout << endl<< "arr "<<arr << endl;
    delete [] arr; // удаляем массив arr 
}

void Fill(int arr[],const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
}

void Show(int arr[],const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }    
}

 void Increase(int arr[],int &size,const int value)
{
    int *newArr = new int[size + 1]; //выделяем место под новый массив на 1 эл. больше

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        newArr[i] = arr[i]; // копируем массив arr в newarr
    }

    size++; // Увеличиваем длинну массива на 1

    newArr[size] = value; // Замняем 6 элемент на value

    delete [] arr; // удаляем массив arr

    arr = newArr;
}
```

Благодарю за ответы, пойду смотреть лекции, как раз скоро на 1 курс.

Comment: & - взять адрес, звездочка - разыменовать (то есть, обратная операция). в многих случаях, зведочка как бы "гасит" один &. Что в данном случае и происходит. `*&a` это и есть само `a`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Итак,

```
*&a == *(&a)
```

`&a` - адрес `a`, указатель, указывающий на память, где находится `a`.

`*&a` - разыменованный указатель `&a`, т.е. значение, на которое указывает указатель. А указывает он (`&a`) на память, где находится `a`, т.е. `*&a == a`...

К вашему обновленному вопросу (ой, не надо так поступать, кардинально меняя вопрос по ходу дела!).

Вы передаете указатель по значению, так что

```
arr = newArr;
```

внутри функции никак не меняет `arr` вне функции. Да и

```
size++; // Увеличиваем длинну массива на 1
newArr[size++] = value; // Замняем 6 элемент на value
```

неверно — вылетаете за границу массива.
Можно сделать так:

```
void Increase(int **arr,int &size,const int value);

...

Increase(&arr,size,value); // Увеличиваем массив на 1

...

void Increase(int **arr,int &size,const int value)
{
    int *newArr = new int[size + 1]; //выделяем место под новый массив на 1 эл. больше

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        newArr[i] = (*arr)[i]; // копируем массив arr в newarr
    }

    //size++; // Увеличиваем длинну массива на 1

    newArr[size++] = value; // Замняем 6 элемент на value

    delete [] *arr; // удаляем массив arr

    *arr = newArr;
}
```

Можно и со ссылкой:

```
void Increase(int *&arr,int &size,const int value);

...

Increase(arr,size,value); // Увеличиваем массив на 1

...


void Increase(int *&arr,int &size,const int value)
{
    int *newArr = new int[size + 1]; //выделяем место под новый массив на 1 эл. больше

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        newArr[i] = arr[i]; // копируем массив arr в newarr
    }

    //size++; // Увеличиваем длинну массива на 1

    newArr[size++] = value; // Замняем 6 элемент на value

    delete [] arr; // удаляем массив arr

    arr = newArr;
}
```

Comment: а потом приходит перегруженный оператор звездочка:) который возвращает указатель (а почему бы и нет) :)

Comment: Спасибо, но я всё равно не понимаю. Что значит **arr? Почему нельзя написать в функцию arr[]? *(arr)[i] я тоже не понимаю. Я , к сожалению, только месяц узучаю c++, много не знаю.

Comment: Первый вопрос - потому что вы передаете значение указателя. Т.е. фактически копию, сама переменная остается неизменной. `(*arr)[i]` означает — разыменуй указатель на указатель `arr`, т.е. получи указатель на массив в памяти, и потом возьми `i`-ый элемент. Я бы советовал вам почитать если не учебник, то что-то типа "С++ для чайников" или "С для чайников", потому что ответ на вопрос предполагает знания, достаточные для его понимания... Заменить ответом несколько лекций — по указателям, функциям и т.п. — не получится...